# relationship row to be deleted on cascade delete

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, cascading-deletes

I have the following entities in a one-to-many relationship:

```
@Entry
class Parent {
    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Child> children;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entry
class Child {
    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
...
    @Transient  
    private Parent parent; 
...
}
```

So – out of these, there are the following 2 entity tables in the database

```
parent(id, ...)
child(id, ..)
```

and the relationship table between these two entities-- due to that `@OneToMany` relationship

```
parent_child(parent_id, child_id)
```

suppose `parent_id=4` has the `child_id=7` and thus `parent_child` table has the row `(parent_id=4, child_id=7)`.

When i delete child id =7,  isn’t the `(parent_id=4, child_id=7)` in `parent_child` table supposed to be deleted as part of it? I’m seeing that row in `parent_child` table even after the corresponding child is deleted from the child table.

I’m using the repository (implementing `CrudRepository`) for deleting that child.

//////////////

**UPDATE:**

by `parent_child(parent_id, child_id)`, i'm referring to the relationship table that hibernate is generating behind the scenes to maintain the relationship between `parent` and `child` tables.

went into this table out of curiosity directly on SQL. and these are what i'm seeing. i expected (still do) the `(parent_id=4, child_id=7)` row would disappear now that `child_id=7` fell off the face of the Earth. but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mapped your entity class like this.

```
   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Parent parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Child> children;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    @Transient  
    private Parent parent;
```

And do @ManyToOne mapping in Child Entity.